# Small- signal analysis of BJT

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn, pnp

Can you explain to me how to obtain the small signal voltages of vc(vout),vb( for the upper BJT) and ve( small-signal voltage of the common emitter ? for this small-signal equivalent circuit. I have tried to do write KCL equations but I think I am not able to find the proper relationships.
[image: circuit]
sorry for image quality. 
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: I can't even understand the annotations.

Comment: What does the u mean, as in r_o = 100ku? Can you show the full schematic so we can verify if your small-signal representation is correct?

Comment: sorry again for my bad hand-writing. its ohm not u. they are resistances.

Comment: Badly drawn circuit, not even sure that small signal model makes any sense, unreadable component value, not even showing an **attempt** at solving the equations. I'm moving on !

Comment: Could you look at it now? I have added the main circuit, hope it will be help full.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with your model. Notice that r_o is significantly larger (40-100 times larger) than than the other resistances in the circuit. What happens if you consider it as infinite resistance and erase it from your circuit? Does the math get significantly easier? I was never any good at generating and solving systems of equations for this kind of circuit. Too much focus on algebra, almost no focus on gaining an intuitive understanding of what the circuit is doing. Always try simulating difficult circuits in LTSPICE, PSPICE, or CircuitLab, too.

Comment: well this could have been an exam question for us without using any computer or program :D

Comment: Experience simulating circuits will help you solve them on paper. It's hard to have confidence in your calculations if you can't/haven't verified them. Exam questions, as important as they are in school, are totally irrelevant to the rest of your life as an engineer. Simulation is a skill you need to build. It will help you tremendously. I don't think I would have graduated if not for PSPICE!

Answer (score 0):

Many times it is best to use simpler equivelent circuits before writing loop or node equations.  The first thing to do in this case is to find the Thevenin equivelent at the base of the npn to ground for vin and the two resistors.  You know how to do this if you are to the point of analyzing circuits like this.  The second thing is to notice that for the PNP i=gm*vbe is the equation of a resistor between C and E.  If you substitute gm=1/r you will find that this is small enough that you can probably ignore the base emitter and collector emitter resistors.  If not just do the parallel combination to replace the PNP with a single resistor.

For the PNP you have B in the wrong place.  Since Vx is a short to ground for small signal, B is the ground end of the PNP r-pi.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to answer this question, I would begin by finding the equivalent input resistance looking into the base of the NPN transistor. This effectively helps reduce the system of 3 equations to a system of two equations due to the fact that, given the input resistance, call it R<sub>b</sub>, you can find the voltage at the base of the NPN transistor. Due to this fact, you can solve for the output voltage of the circuit in terms of a test base voltage (V<sub>b</sub>):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcumvz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will give you $$\frac{V_o}{V_b}$$ In order to find $$\frac{V_o}{V_{in}
}$$ you would need to solve for $$\frac{V_b}{V_{in}}$$ and find the product of these results. The latter can be found by using the voltage divider between the 2.2kOhm resistor and the 1890 Ohm resistor in parallel with the base resistance. Additionally, to simplify further, you can find the resistance looking down into the emitter of the PNP transistor and treat it as an AC resistance. Hopefully this helps you answer the question!